Выбор повторяющихся значений в нескольких столбцах
Необходимо написать запрос в общем виде для отображения повторяющихся значений в одном столбце только в том случае, если им соответствуют повторяющиеся значения (другие) в другом столбце.
Например, есть два столбца:

Ожидаемый результат:

Через count(значения первого столбца) >1 AND count(значения второго столбца) >1 не получается, т.к. выводятся просто все значения по двум столбцам, количество которых > 1.
Нужно именно как-то связать столбцы между собой: искать повторы по другим столбцам в рамках повторов в первом столбце.
При этом не конкретных повторов, а общее правило задать, т.к. таблица огромная.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

Получите в подзапросе количество для каждой уникальной пары, отберите, где оно больше единицы, затем либо JOIN к исходной таблице, либо просто генерация посчитанного количества записей. Для СУБД, поддерживающей оконные функции и CTE - соответственно оконный COUNT().

Ну да, group by по обоим столбцам, плюс having count, делов то.

Для СУБД, не поддерживающих CTE и оконные функции:
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT col1, col2
               FROM table t2
               GROUP BY 1, 2
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) t3

Для СУБД, поддерживающих CTE и оконные функции:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2) cnt
    FROM table
    )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;

